# Как освобождать память в MemoryStream

Tags: c#, память

Во время работы приложения в память читаются 5 и больше файлов, во время чтения файлов используется от 1gb до 5gb памяти.

Хотя должно использоваться только 1gb, так как каждый исходный файл который читает MemoryStream по 1gb. `flush/close` вроде делаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Как правильно освобождать память перед чтением нового файла в память?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string filePath;
    string[] files = {
        "C:\\001.txt", "C:\\002.txt", "C:\\003.txt", "C:\\004.txt", "C:\\005.txt", "C:\\006.txt", "C:\\007.txt", "C:\\008.txt"
    };

    //
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {

        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(files[i]);
        using(fileStream) {

            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);

            int l = (int) fileStream.Length;
            fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, l);

            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memStream, Encoding.Default)) {

            }

            memStream.Flush();
            memStream.Close();

        }

        fileStream.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Надо сбрасывать ссылку на объект, приравняв его к null и вызывать GC

Comment: Deadkenny, а как это для моего кода будет выглядеть? GC это что?

Comment: сделал (но не помогло)
sr = null; memSteam = null; fileStream = null; 
что еще сделать?

Comment: @prog432 ниже ответил.

Comment: using ( fileStream  ) здесь открывайте файл через streamreader, после выхода из юзинга - он будет гарантированно убит. Не нужно заморачиваться с мусоросборщиком как вам советуют.

Comment: @pincher1519 У него все это делается в цикле, поэтому сборщик не будет вызван во время. Поэтому как раз вызов его вручную - правильное решение в данном случае.

Comment: @deadkenny, using внутри цикла, все должно вызываться.

А если я не прав, тогда лучше это чтение вынести в отдельную процедуру и опять не заморачиваться с чисткой мусора вручную.

Answer (score 12):

`MemoryStream` имплементирует `IDisposable`. Так что вы можете просто вызвать `Dispose` (или лучше обернуть объект в `using`). Полагаться на `GC.Collect` — ужасный стиль программирования, старайтесь избегать его как огня.

С другой стороны, для вашей задачи `MemoryStream` и не нужен, почему бы просто не надеть `StreamReader` на `FileStream`?

Сама идея `StreamReader`'а как раз и состоит в том, чтобы не читать файл целиком, с диким расходом памяти и просадкой производительности, а по кусочкам, по мере надобности, держа в памяти каждый раз только нужное. Вы же считываете *весь* файл в `MemoryStream`, сводя на нет всё преимущество поточного чтения.

Answer (score 2):

```
memStream = null; 
GC.Collect();
```

GC - garbage collector. Сборщик мусора.

И прочитайте как пользоваться using, а также про символ @.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Deadkenny помогло но иногда кушает 2gb
что еще делать?

Comment: Смотреть где еще может быть не освобожденная память и освобождать. Например там еще StreamReader у вас есть. Ну и посмотреть на размеры файлов. Может быть 2 гигабайта это норма?

Comment: сделал уже вот так (но 2 гига иногда кушается, все файлы ровно 1gb)
непонятно что кушается

sr.Close();   sr = null;   if (sr != null) { sr.Dispose(); }; GC.Collect();
memStream.Flush();  memStream.Close();  memStream = null;   if (memStream != null) { memStream.Dispose(); };  GC.Collect();
fileStream.Close(); fileStream = null; if (fileStream != null) { fileStream.Dispose(); };         GC.Collect();

Comment: @Deadkenny освобождать память таким способом, когда класс имплементит IDisposable - это что-то из разряда легких извращений

Comment: @prog432: А это чтобы уж наверняка:

    memStream = null;
    if (memStream != null) { memStream.Dispose(); };

? (Контрольный выстрел, так сказать.)

Comment: @DreamChild да может выглядеть как извращение, но вопрос звучал примерно так: "Процесс занимает 5 гигабайт, хочу что бы было 1 гигабайт". Без явного вызова коллектора память посередине цикла не освободится.

Comment: @DreamChild и кстати, хоть потоки и Disposable, процесс все равно после всех операций может держать память занятой, до того случая, пока она не понадобится. Т.е. например занято было 5 гигов и процесс так и будет работать с занятыми 5 гигами.

Comment: >Без явного вызова коллектора память посередине цикла не освободится

с чего вы это взяли? Можете это подтвердить чем-то более весомым, нежели "я так считаю"?

>процесс все равно после всех операций может держать память занятой, до того случая, пока она не понадобится

 аналогичный вопрос - с чего вы взяли, и можете ли чем-то подтвердить?

Comment: @DreamChild не подтвержу, но скажу что у меня была подобная проблема. Правда память не освобождалась не из-за Stream, а из-за не Disposable объекта и приходилось обнулять указатель для очистки памяти.

Comment: если честно, звучит сомнительно. Нет, я не сомневаюсь, что у вас были такие случаи, однако не вижу ни единой причины пользоваться этим методом тут и не использовать Dispose. Конечно, изредка бывают ситуации, когда стоит использовать GC.Collect, но на это должны быть серьезные основания, особенно когда имеется disposable-класс. Собственно, смысл Dispose в том и есть, чтобы обеспечить детерминированное освобождение ресурсов. В частности, внутри циклов Dispose точно так же своевременно освобождает ресурсы. Все-таки ваш способ - это реально дурная практика